# Changing the filename of a Core Data Managed Object Model

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, core-data

How do you change the filename of a Core Data managed object model?

I would like to change the filename for the Core Data managed object model in my Xcode project.  I am not concerned about any migration issues.

I currently access the file in my code this way:

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"Template" ofType:@"momd"];
```

I have not found a way to change the momd filename/package that does not result in Xcode failing to find the changed filename.

Comment: have you drag the file with new name or rename the existing file?

Comment: This might be silly--but you tried right-clicking on the file in Xcode and choosing Rename... there?

Comment: The name shown in Xcode under groups is not the filename of the managed object model -- nor is it the name of the file that you use in code when you load the managed object model.

Comment: I believe this is the problem I am seeing: http://openradar.appspot.com/7500956.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this is the cause: http://openradar.appspot.com/7500956

Comment: Bugreports do not belong outsite Apples Bugreporter.

Comment: It means someone doesn't like openradar :)

Answer (score 6):

You have a hidden file `.xcurrentversion` inside the `"model".xcdatamodeld`.

Just edit this file to match your model's new name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs$
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>_XCCurrentVersionName</key>
        <!-- This name should be the same as the file name !-->
        <string>"model".xcdatamodel</string> 
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 4):

Done that several times.

Simply rename the xcdmodel and take care of the name when you load it from the bundle. Before you run, make sure to clean the target. (Eg remove all precompiled files, else he think he did compile the model already and thus your app fails to load the momd since they are there with the wrong name)

Comment: In the past, the simulator has mysteriously kept old .mom and .momd files. I recommend deleting the app off the simulator after you make such a name change.

Comment: Seconding TechZen's suggestion. Past versions of Xcode gave us bizarre behaviour unless we deleted the app, and also cleared out the "DerivedData" folder to boot. Haven't seen that in a while though so bet it's fixed in the latest ver.

Comment: I was struggling with this issue for some hours and deleting the app off the simulator solved it. So, this is still happening with Xcode 5. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Also make sure to edit in AppDelegate like managedObjectModel  and persistentStoreCoordinator